# How can I use a C# list within signalr javascript file?

Tags: c#, list, signalr

My ASP.NET project is using signalr to continuously update a web page every second with new information that enters the database. So the web page is only receiving information, not sending it. I have successfully been able to send an array from the hub towards my javascript file, and my web page correctly displayed all of the information. However, I would like to achieve the same result by using a C# list.

I have a Hub that looks like the following, and I am trying to send a C# list of items that is fetched from the GetListOfItems() method toward the javascript file:

```
public class DatabaseDisplayHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        await UpdateDatabase();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the updated information to the clients connected to the web interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task UpdateDatabase()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateDatabase", Startup._eventsDatabase.GetListOfItems());

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

My javascript file receives the list as a parameter to the function when a connection is established, and then tries to access several of the item's fields to display them on the HTML page.

```
"use strict";

// Connects to the DaabaseDisplayHub.cs to be automatically updated with the new information to display.
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/databaseDisplayHub").build();

// Called when the DatabaseDisplayHub sends the new information to display to the connected clients.
connection.on("UpdateDatabase", function (eventList) {
    var eventsBody = document.getElementById("eventsBody");

    while (eventsBody.firstChild) {
        eventsBody.removeChild(eventsBody.firstChild);
    }

    eventList.foreach(eventItem => {
        var eventsRow = document.createElement("tr");
        eventsBody.appendChild(eventsRow);

        var eventIdentifier_TD = document.createElement("td");
        eventIdentifier_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.eventIdentifier;
        eventsRow.appendChild(eventIdentifier_TD);

        var EventActive_TD = document.createElement("td");
        EventActive_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.eventActive;
        eventsRow.appendChild(EventActive_TD);

        var Car_TD = document.createElement("td");
        Car_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.car;
        eventsRow.appendChild(Car_TD);

        var StartTimeStamp_TD = document.createElement("td");
        StartTimeStamp_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.startTimeStamp;
        eventsRow.appendChild(StartTimeStamp_TD);

        var EndTimeStamp_TD = document.createElement("td");
        EndTimeStamp_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.endTimeStamp;
        eventsRow.appendChild(EndTimeStamp_TD);
    });
});

// Called when the connection with the Hub is closed.
connection.onclose(function () {
    alert("Disconnected from server.");
    console.log("Database Page Disconnected.");
});

// Connects the WebSocket to the DatabaseDisplayHub. 
connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log("Connected to database hub");
}).catch(function (err) {
    alert("Error while connecting to server.");
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

I have tried debugging the javascript code through chrome developer tools, but I can't seem to understand why the list fields are not being displayed. I'm wondering whether the C# list is not compatible inside the javascript file. I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution to be able to access the contents of the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I take a C# List and serialize it like this:

```
Clients.Caller.ReportData(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(reporthosttable));
```

In my client JS file receive that like this:

```
chat.client.reportData = function (reportData) {
    var data = JSON.parse(reportData);
    //do stuff with data    
}
```

Other solutions exist I am sure... this is what works for me in a similar scenario where there are large data sets queried from a database, converted to a C# List and then send to client for display on a repeated basis.

Comment: Hey, your solution didn't exactly work for me because I couldn't figure out how to add a reference to JavaScriptSerializer (I couldn't seem to find it?). But your parsing suggestion helped me find a solution for my project, so thank you very much for nudging me in the right direction. I'm adding my solution as an answer to my question!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You should find the JavaScriptSerializer setting this - using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out thanks to the nudge received from one of the answers below.

I used the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method found within the `Newtonsoft.Json` package to convert my C# list to a Json string.

```
// Within my Hub class
await Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateDatabase", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Startup._eventsDatabase.GetListOfItems()));
```

Then, within my JavaScript file, I had to parse that string using JSON.parse() for it to be in the proper form so that I can access each object's properties.

```
// Within my JavasScript file
    connection.on("UpdateDatabase", function (eventList) {

    var eventObject = JSON.parse(eventList);

    var eventsBody = document.getElementById("eventsBody");

    while (eventsBody.firstChild) {
        eventsBody.removeChild(eventsBody.firstChild);
    }

    eventObject.forEach(function(eventItem) {
        var eventsRow = document.createElement("tr");
        eventsBody.appendChild(eventsRow);

        var eventIdentifier_TD = document.createElement("td");
        eventIdentifier_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.EventIdentifier;
        eventsRow.appendChild(eventIdentifier_TD);

        var EventActive_TD = document.createElement("td");
        EventActive_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.EventActive;
        eventsRow.appendChild(EventActive_TD);

        var Car_TD = document.createElement("td");
        Car_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.Car;
        eventsRow.appendChild(Car_TD);

        var StartTimeStamp_TD = document.createElement("td");
        StartTimeStamp_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.StartTimeStamp;
        eventsRow.appendChild(StartTimeStamp_TD);

        var EndTimeStamp_TD = document.createElement("td");
        EndTimeStamp_TD.innerHTML = eventItem.EndTimeStamp;
        eventsRow.appendChild(EndTimeStamp_TD);
    });
});
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed and is extra overhead for each method call. What is the type returned from `GetListOfItems()`? Did `eventItem` in the browser debugger show you what the object looked like? Like maybe it was `eventItem.EventIdentifier` instead of `eventItem.eventIdentifier`. You could also look at the network traffic and see what the payload was that the server sent back to the client.

Comment: The return type is a List of a user-defined object that I created. That's what I thought originally as well but nothing was working so I'll take this fix for now. There wasn't any information about `eventItem` in the browser debugger, and I also tried to change the capitalization of the first letter of each property but that didn't work either. I'm still a student and relatively new to all this stuff, so I don't know how to verify the network traffic